# java p2p video library?

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

is any such library available either commercial or open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, there is no such open source library.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to update this thread and note that we've created such a library at Frozen Mountain; it's called [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink). The server portion (STUN/TURN, which is used for NAT traveral and IP discovery) is available on Java (in addition to .NET, Mac, etc) and there's a full Java library implementation for the actual P2P communication and audio/video encoding/decoding/rendering. It's also WebRTC-compliant, and communicates nicely with Chrome, etc.

We've released out VP8 Java wrapper as well: https://jvp8.codeplex.com/

(Disclaimer: I work @ FM).

Answer (score 3):

After google searching this a bit as well as from my experience, I don't know of any. If you do find one, I would probably also wonder about its fidelity. Maybe it would be a good idea for you to start your own open source project for this.